# Tauber theorem?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{a_k}{x^k}} $, where $a_k\ge0 $, and when $0 \le x < 1$ , $f(x)$ converges. Then please show that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{{n + 1}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_k}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {1^ - }} (1 - x)f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypothesis is that $A_n=(n+1)C+o(n)$ for a given $C$, with $A_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_k$. Thus, for every positive $\varepsilon$ there exists some finite $B_a$ and $B'_a$ such that $(C-\varepsilon)(n+1)+B_a\leqslant A_n\leqslant (C+\varepsilon)(n+1)+B'_a$ for every $n$. To use this fact, rewrite $f(x)$ for every $x$ in $[0,1)$ as
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}A_nx^n(1-x).
$$
Since $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n(1-x)=1$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+1)x^n(1-x)=\frac1{1-x}$, this yields, for every $x$ in $[0,1)$,
$$
C-\varepsilon+B_a(1-x)\leqslant(1-x)f(x)\leqslant C+\varepsilon+B'_a(1-x).
$$
Since $a$ is as small as one wants, this proves that $(1-x)f(x)\to C$ when $x\to1$, $x<1$.

**Notes:** (1) The hypothesis that $a_n$ is nonnegative is not needed. (2) If the limit $C$ of $\frac1{n+1}A_n$ is $-\infty$ or $+\infty$, one-sided versions of the proof above still apply to show that $(1-x)f(x)\to C$ when $x\to1$, $x<1$.

**Edit** (This is to answer a question asked by the OP in a comment.)

If $a_n$ may be positive or negative, $(1-x)f(x)$ may have a finite limit when $x\to1$, $x<1$, although $C_n=\frac1{n+1}A_n$ diverges. For example, if $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}n$ for every nonnegative $n$, the limit points of $(C_n)_n$ are $\pm\frac12$ hence $(C_n)_n$ diverges but $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$ hence $(1-x)f(x)\to0$.

Comment: If $a_n$ can be negative, how do you justify the rearrangement of the series to $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}A_nx^n(1-x)$?

Comment: @joriki, by the fact that $a_n=A_n-A_{n-1}$ and the convergence of both series $\sum A_nx^n$ and $\sum A_{n-1}x^n$ when $A$ is finite.

Comment: I see -- thanks. Nice proof.

Comment: @joriki, correction: one does not even need $A$ to be finite for the series $\sum A_nx^n$ and $\sum A_{n-1}x^n$ to converge for every $x<1$, this follows from the hypothesis that $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for every $x<1$.

Comment: @joriki, thanks for having checked it.

Comment: If we drop the condition that all ${a_i} \ge 0$, can we conclude that the inexistence of limit on one side is equivalent to the inexistence on the other side?

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\to\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ as $n\to\infty$

$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k}{f(x)}\to 1$ as $x\to 1$

$(n+1)(1-x)=1-x+n-nx=0$ when $x=1$

$\lim {(n+1)(1-x)}=\lim {\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k}{f(x)}}$

multiply both sides by $\frac{f(x)}{n+1}$

lim $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k= \lim(1-x)f(x)$

Comment: It is possible that $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{a_k}}  = \infty $, so the second inference is untenable.

Comment: Hi Angela, I guess your argument need some clarifications.
For example: Why this limit 
$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k}{f(x)}$
exists ?

Comment: I guess that this statement  $\lim {(n+1)(1-x)}=\lim {\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k}{f(x)}}$ need more work, because of the left hand side become infinity unless $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

the proof of this fact is presented in details in *Tauberian Theory: a century of developments* by Jacob Korevaar. In this text the result you are looking for is the Theorem 12.1 at [page 22](http://books.google.com/books?id=Kh_nJe1ZWDoC&pg=PA22).

Note that in your case the second Tauberian condition of the Theorem is satisfied, with $A$ (there) possibly being infinity.

**Edition**  As observed by the questioner the theorem quoted above, give us just a partial answer for this question.

Comment: Why does $\left| {n({a_n} - {a_{n - 1}})} \right| \le C$ or $n({a_n} - {a_{n - 1}}) \ge  - C$ hold in this situation?

Comment: You right Adterram, the theorem I quoted it is not strong enough to prove your claim. I will think about the problem a little bit more.