# $ (1-x)^2\sum_{N+1}^\infty (n+1)x^n = x^{n+1}(n+2 - (n+1)x) $ small independent of $x\in (0,1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527408/cesaro-summable-implies-abel-summable) post a user made the following claim:

**Claim:** Suppose $\rho_n$ is a sequence of real non-negative numbers converging to $0$. Suppose $x\in (0,1)$. Then 
$$
\sum_{N+1}^\infty (n+1)(1-x)^2x^n\rho_n
$$
is small for $N$ large, and $N$ can be chosen independently from $x$.

---

I'm not seeing how this is true. I calculate that 
$$
(1-x)^2\sum_{N+1}^\infty (n+1)x^n = x^{n+1}(n+2 - (n+1)x)
$$
so this part does not seem small independently of $x$. Can anyone justify this claim, or else confirm it is not true? (Perhaps, but I don't think so, there is some other contextual detail which makes his claim true in the linked answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\rho _n} = 0$, then $\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists {N_\varepsilon } \in \mathbb{N},n \geqslant {N_\varepsilon } \Rightarrow {\rho _n} < \varepsilon $

So,

$\sum\limits_{n = {N_\varepsilon } + 1}^\infty  {\left( {n + 1} \right){{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}{x^n}{\rho _n}}  \leqslant \varepsilon \sum\limits_{n = {N_\varepsilon } + 1}^\infty  {\left( {n + 1} \right){{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}{x^n}}  = \varepsilon {\left( {1 - x} \right)^2}\left( {n + 2 - \left( {n + 1} \right)x} \right)$

which is arbitrarily small, independent of $x \in \left( {0,1} \right)$ (it is only dependent on the sequence ${\rho _n}$ and ${N_\varepsilon }$ is dependent only on $\varepsilon $).