# $a_n=O(\frac{1}{n}),\ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^nS_k}{n}$ converges $\Rightarrow S_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $n|a_n|\le M\ \forall n$ for some positive number $M$. We define the sequences $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $\sigma_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nS_k}{n}\ \forall n$. Then we have the following result:
 $(\sigma_n)$ converges $\Rightarrow (S_n)$ converges.
I think I have seen this result before and I think it has a specific name, but I can't remember it. Does anyone know its name ? And could someone provide me with a proof or some tips on how to prove it ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The converse of this statement follows directly from Stolz-Cesàro theorem

Comment: @PetwrForeman Isn't the implication in the other direction? Edit: I missed the "converse" in your comment.

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes I agree that the converse is a consequence of Stolz-Cesaro theorem. But I'm looking for a proof for the direct implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are right, but the OP’s implication is actually correct.

[Cesaro summable implies Abel summable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527408/cesaro-summable-implies-abel-summable#640850)
shows that in your situation, the sequence $\sum{S_n-S_{n-1}}$ is Cesaro-summable, so is Abel summable.

Now, $S_n-S_{n-1}=O(1/n)$, so by the examples of Tauber theorems here ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_Tauberian_theorems ) $\sum{S_n-S_{n-1}}$ converges.