# Explaining a relation used in a proof of "Cesaro summable implies Abel summable"

Tags: complex-analysis, cesaro-summable

In this post: [Cesaro summable implies Abel summable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527408/cesaro-summable-implies-abel-summable), in the proof that Cesaro summable implies Abel summable, the following relation is used:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^1_n x^n = (1-x)^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^0_n x^n = (1-x)^{-2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

I know that the series $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$ for $|r| \lt 1$, so the standard geometric series. What I see in the relation is the following: $a = s_n^1, \ r = x$  and $s_n^1 = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} s_n^0$  (as defned in the proof).

Following this, I would expect $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^1_n x^n = \frac{s_n^1}{1-x} = (1-x)^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}s_n^0$$.

But why is it $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}s_n^0 x^n$? Where does the $x^n$ come from?

Comment: There is a minor typo in the linked answer, it's $$s_n^1 := \sum_{k=0}^{n} s_k^0$$ and so it depends on $n$, so you cannot get it out of the sum.

Comment: @BrunoB so if I understand correctly, you HAVE to carry the $x^n$ to the next sum?